# I am not using any launch images warning issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I am not using any *launch images* for project but it shows *yellow sign(which is a warning sign)* in the xcode.
Is there any idea how to solve this warning? I am unable to understand that I have not any launching image then why it is showing error?

[image]

Comment: what is warning message displayed ???

Comment: @iPatel it just shows yellow sign

Comment: Solve it by using a launch image.......

Comment: @borrden i have also not used in other app luanch images but they are not showing any warning this app is showing error any idea how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your launch images, as of iOS 5, at least four for the iPad and two for the iPhone. Name your images as follows: (The name I am using is only an example, you can use any you want.)

```
iPadLaunchImage-Portrait.png
iPadLaunchImage-Portrait@2x.png
iPadLaunchImage-Landscape.png
iPadLaunchImage-Landscape@2x.png

iPhoneLaunchImage.png
iPhoneLaunchImage@2x.png
```

Make sure you use a distinct name for each device. You have more options available for the iPad, which you can read about in the documentation.

Place all of these images in the top of your app's bundle directory. Then all you do is add two keys to YourApp-Info.plist.

```
Launch Image(iPad) string iPadLaunchImage
Launch Image(iPhone) string iPhoneLaunchImage
```

Comment: I want that is should no image specified instead of yellow sign i have other project in that it is showing no images specified

Comment: Just right click on that and click on the showinfinder then it shows the Image incase it takes any default image.